# Intuitive explanation of what happens when we remove functions from integrals by exploiting bounds

Tags: integration

Suppose I have an integral like,

$$ P = \int_{0}^{\pi} x \sin x \cos^4 x dx$$

by the property,

$$ \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx =  \int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx$$

And, we do

$$ P = \int_{0}^{\pi} (\pi -x) \sin x \cos^4 x dx $$

Now if we add the first integral and this new one, we get

$$ P= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cos^4 x dx$$

Now, why did the integrand dependent  becoming independent of it at the end? why does the $\pi$ factor account for the removal of 'x'? I have seen many integrals where this trick was used to remove some functio in integrand to make it simpler but I never understood why it works.

The kind of answer I am looking for: A geometrical / graphical approach (if possible)

Comment: Notice, after adding you must get $$ P= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cos^4 x dx=\pi \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin x \cos^4 x dx$$

Comment: I think the answer you want may lie more generally in linear algebra. A function, when viewed as a vector in an infinite dimensional vector space, condenses down to just one scalar after an operation. While not mystifying at first, this premise leads us to odd conclusions such as these. Ultimately, the idea is a projection - given the bounds of an integral - some functions will "project" down in the same, certain symmetrical ways as other functions as they "lie in each other's projection shadow" as it were. For integrals, the "direction" of projection is characterized by these symmetries.

Comment: can u explain this in more detai pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to think of $\int x dx$ first. We get

$$
P = \int_0^1x dx \quad (1)\\
= \int_0^1(1 - x)dx \\
= \int_0^1 1dx  - \int_0^1x dx \quad [(2) - (3)] \\
= 1 - P \\
\therefore P = 1/2
$$

We can draw this pictorially as:

[image]

The core idea is the duality of $g(x) = (1- x)$ when $f(x) = 1-x$:

- We can consider $\int (1-x)dx$ as performing the original integral "right to left"
- But we can *also* interpret it as doing the original integral "top to bottom"

When doing as "top to bottom", we wind up recovering the original term $\int f(x) dx$ as being subtracted from the full area of $\int 1 dx$. This lets us get a "copy" of the integral $P$.

Comment: Awesome answer ! but I want a way to see for this one too :P